# Jasperserver 6 optimized JVM settings

Tags: tomcat, jvm, java-7, jasperserver, jvm-arguments

I know i am asking a very wage question but i have checked many links on JVM optimization but do not come across any satisfactory answer.

My goal is to put optimised JVM allocation to the tomcat 7 running jasperserver 6.0.1 with 4 GB ram.

There are not a lot scheduled reports but yes the reports which are scheduled can reach up-to a 10 MB space and same amount has to be mailed to the users. I also know that there are some schedulers whose time coincides so they must be hitting the server at the same time.

Total numbers of users in the application is some what around 800 but i have never seen more than 50 users using application at once.

Based on it i come to below settings for tomcat 7

```
-Xmx1024M
-Duser.timezone=Europe/London
-XX:PermSize=128m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Dcatalina.home=D:\Tomcat7Jasper6
-Dcatalina.base=D:\Tomcat7Jasper6
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=D:\Tomcat7Jasper6\endorsed
-Djava.io.tmpdir=D:\Tomcat7Jasper6\temp
-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=D:\Tomcat7Jasper6\conf\logging.properties
```

Now the issue is there are some problems i faced with these settings

1) When i ran a report from the screen it ran fine, but when it ran from the scheduler it send me GC error.

> Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

2) I want tomcat 7 to automatically extract the heap dump and thread dump if any time there is heap full or cpu reaches 100%. Is it possible to put some settings like this.

Please if some one can help who performed the JVM setting optimization in tomcat 7 for jasperserver.

I am using

> Tomcat - Tomcat 7
>
> Java - jdk 1.7.0_79
>
> Jasperserver - Jasperserver 6.0.1
>
> RAM - 4 GB
>
> OS - Windows server 2012 R2 Standard 64 bit
>
> Processor - L5640 @ 2.27 Ghz (2 processors)